# How to access value of child element in a object?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I want to access friends array of every user  (values of the array are user's id's) and return the value of the friend's array of the given user (friend)

```
const users = [
{
   "id": 1,
   "firstName": "Paul",
   "surname": "Crowe",
   "friends": [2]
 },
 {
   "id": 2,
   "firstName": "Rob",
   "surname": "Fitz",
   "friends": [1,3]
 },
 {
   "id": 3,
   "firstName": "Ben",
   "surname": "O'Carolan",
   "friends": [2]
 },
```

This is what I have tried:

```
const fof = users.filter(user => {
      if (friend == user.id) {
        return true;
      }
    });
```

Comment: `friend` is undefined in your bottom snippet, from what you have shown us.

Comment: What's the given friend? Note that index numbers are 0 based.

Comment: can you show us what's the expected result?

Comment: given friend mines every number/friend in the array

Comment: the expected result for the second user would be [2] , because both of his friends are friends with the second user.

Comment: I have to note that I need to cycle through 20 of similar users and get that info

Answer (score 0):

**Updated** now that I see your response about the expected output.

```
function getFriendsOfFriends(userId) {
  const user = users.find(u => userId === u.id);
  const userFriends = user.friends;

  let friendsOfFriends = [];
  for (let i = 0, l = userFriends.length; i < l; i ++) {
    const myFriendId = userFriends[i];
    const myFriend = users.find(u => myFriendId === u.id);
    friendsOfFriends = friendsOfFriends.concat(myFriend.friends);
  }
  // remove duplicates
  friendsOfFriends = friendsOfFriends.reduce((acc, curr) => {
    if (acc.indexOf(curr) === -1) {
      acc.push(curr);
    }
    return acc;
  }, []);
  return friendsOfFriends;
}
```

This does a few things:

- Find the user by `id`
- Get the list of their friends' `id`s
- Loop through the list of friends' `id` and:

  - get that user & their friends
  - collect all friends of friends' ids in a single array
- After looping through the user's friends, remove duplicates from the `friendsOfFriends` array.

**Added: looping through all users**

```
const friendsOfFriendsForEachUser  = {};
for (let i = 0, l = users.length; i < l; i ++) {
  const user = users[i];
  const friendsOfFriends = getFriendsOfFriends(user.id);
  friendsOfFriendsForEachUser[user.id] = friendsOfFriends;
}
```

This will store friends of friends in a dictionary. The loop can be adjusted, depending on how you need to store & access the information.

Comment: it returns that friend is undefined

Comment: @pavlejovanovic I've edited my answer - I meant to use `friendId` to search through the array users initially. That should not give you an undefined error.

Comment: I have to note that I need to cycle through 20 of similar users and get that info but for the simplicity reasons I only wrote 3 users here

Comment: I have tried your updated solution but it returns undefined arrays, possibly because value of  `user` in the arrow function is declared but never read

Comment: @pavlejovanovic Take a look again. I've updated now that you gave us the expected output.

Comment: @pavlejovanovic Take a look here: https://codepen.io/ebbishop/pen/LYVRmpL. Open the console (button at the bottom left) and update line 43 with whichever id you'd like to try. It gives the output you ask for.

Comment: Thanks for that but ...This is working and it is finding the right info I just need it to do it for every user not only for user 2. I have to note that I need to cycle through 20 of similar users and get that info but for the simplicity reasons I only wrote 3 users here

Comment: So loop through the users and call the function for each one.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `filter` method to find friend and then just `map` his friends:

```
const idPerson = 2;
const idFriends = users.filter(f => f.id == idPerson).flatMap(({friends})=> (friends));
const uniqueUsers = new Map(users.map(u => ([u.id, u])));
const friends = idFriends.map(id => ({...uniqueUsers.get(id)}));
```

An example:

```js
const users = [
    {
        "id": 1,
        "firstName": "Paul",
        "surname": "Crowe",
        "friends": [2]
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "firstName": "Rob",
        "surname": "Fitz",
        "friends": [1, 3]
    },
    {
        "id": 3,
        "firstName": "Ben",
        "surname": "O'Carolan",
        "friends": [2]
    }
];

const idPerson = 2;
const idFriends = users.filter(f => f.id == idPerson).flatMap(({friends})=> (friends));
const uniqueUsers = new Map(users.map(u => ([u.id, u])));
const friends = idFriends.map(id => ({...uniqueUsers.get(id)}));
console.log(friends);
```

Comment: this could work but I need to cycle through 20 of these users

Comment: and hardcoding it is not a option

Comment: @pavlejovanovic could you say what do you mean by hardcoding? Could you add desired output? Thanks

Comment: the expected result for the second user would be [2] , because both of his friends are friends with the second user.

Comment: This is working and it is finding the right info I just need it to do it for every user not only for user 2. I have to note that I need to cycle through 20 of similar users and get that info but for the simplicity reasons I only wrote 3 users here

Comment: @pavlejovanovic you can create a loop and iterate to find friends

Answer (score 0):

when you have a big array, find() is more effective. it'll return the first element matches the condition

```
const findFOF = (id) => users.find(item => item.id === id).friends
```